# cv_bridge converter tutorial not compiling

Tags: cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Users,
following the tutorial described at http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages
I'm experimenting problem on compiling:

In function `ImageConverter::ImageConverter()': converter_demo.cpp:(.text._ZN14ImageConverterC2Ev[_ZN14ImageConverterC5Ev]+0x62): undefined reference to` image_transport::ImageTransport::ImageTransport(ros::NodeHandle const&)'

In the package.xml file, I declared the followind dependencies:

buildtool_depend: catkin, roscpp, rospy, std_msgs, image_transport, cv_bridge

run_depend: roscpp, rospy, std_msgs, image_transport, cv_bridge

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196192/cv_bridge-converter-tutorial-not-compiling/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2014-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

buildtool_depend must only be catkin. The others mentioned there have to be build_depend

E.g.:

```
  <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>

  <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rospy</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>image_transport</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cv_bridge</build_depend>
  
  <run_depend>roscpp</run_depend>
  <run_depend>rospy</run_depend>
  <run_depend>std_msgs</run_depend>
  <run_depend>image_transport</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cv_pridge</run_depend>
```

Further, you have to find_package them in your CMakeLists.txt (in case you not yet have):

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs image_transport cv_bridge)
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on 2014-10-29**:
I "missed" the find package :)
Now it works, thank you!